# AudioBuffer not cachable / decodeAudioData takes to long

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to write a custom web player for music using the Web Audio Api, but I'm running into a problem decoding the audio.

I'm fetching the .mp3 as ArrayBuffer from my backend and decode it, using the AudioContext.decodeAudioData function.

```
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  const raw = await resp.arrayBuffer();
  const audioBuffer = context.decodeAudioData(raw);
```

I'm trying to cache the AudioBuffer in an IndexedDB, but it is not clonable. The decoding takes about 10 seconds on my device with a regular mp3 and thats pretty long. Do I have any other choice to prevent long wait times between songs (apart from prefetching and "predecoding")?

Comment: Can't you fetch the data as a stream and decode it in parts?

Comment: Decoding it in parts seems to be fairly complicated, because the javascript clock is very inaccurate. I tried it, but I could't stop the crackling between the pieces of audio. Additionally the documentation says:

"Asynchronously decodes audio file data contained in an ArrayBuffer. In this case, the ArrayBuffer is usually loaded from an XMLHttpRequest's response attribute after setting the responseType to arraybuffer. This method only works on complete files, not fragments of audio files." https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/AudioContext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AudioBuffer` are not meant for large pieces of audio

> This interface represents a memory-resident audio asset (**for one-shot sounds and other short audio clips**). Its format is non-interleaved IEEE 32-bit linear PCM with a nominal range of -1 -> +1. It can contain one or more channels. Typically, it would be expected that the length of the PCM data would be **fairly short (usually somewhat less than a minute)**. For longer sounds, such as music soundtracks, **streaming should be used with the audio element and MediaElementAudioSourceNode**.

(emphasis mine)

https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioBuffer

You might want to look into [MediaElementAudioSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode) if you actually need to manipulate the audio on the fly. Otherwise a simple audio element should suffice.

Comment: Oh damn, so I totally abused the decodeAudioBuffer method. Thank you for the clarification, I will try implementing the player with the html element.

Comment: @Prinzhorn, MediaElementAudioSourceNode appears to be meant to be used in conjunction with HTML5. Is there a Node.js module for longer audio that I can use alongside the Web Audio Api module for shorter sounds?

Comment: @WesModes what exactly are you doing with the audio in a Node process? Depending on the use-case this might not be a good idea, as a call to `decodeAudioData` will block your whole Node process. However, if that's not an issue for you (e.g. you spawn a second process) then just use `decodeAudioData` even for large files. You don't have to deal with network latency if the audio files are local, which you have to in the browsers.